# How do I pass common powershell command line parameters between cmdlets on the pipeline?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

Say I've got two cmdlets, 'new-foo' and 'do-bar'.  Both cmdlets need to authenticate to a service in order to perform their action, and 'do-bar' takes a foo.  Today, I can do:

```
new-foo -host localhost -username user -password password -whateverOtherArgs
```

And I can do:

```
do-bar -host localhost -username user -password password -foo myFoo
```

And I can even chain them passing foo on the pipeline, e.g.:

```
new-foo <blah blah> | do-bar -host localhost -username user -password password
```

But I can't figure out how to pass the common parameters, such as the service location and the credentials between elements of the pipeline.  If I've got a bunch of my cmdlets chained together I'd like to only pass the credentials the first time, and then re-use those for the rest of the pipeline.

What am I missing, seems like this should be obvious ...

Answer (score 1):

You could have New-Foo spit out an object that contains both the original object that do-bar is interested in as well as the service location and the credentials as properties. Accept this object as a parameter and then pluck out the data you need *if* the user doesn't supply the ServiceLocation or Credential parameters.

Comment: This is what I do.  Alternatively, if do-bar is a helper function being called directly by new-foo, you can use Powershell 2.0's new splat operator -- either on a psobject you project out yourself, or on @args directly.

Comment: Ugh, but what if I'm not in control of the object types per-se?   I've been trying to figure out if add-member(?) can work if called from inside my cmdlet, or if I can add a property to an object dynamically ala python or ruby, but I'm a .NET newb.  Maybe with .net4 and the dynamic type?

Answer (score 0):

does [Get-Credential](http://ss64.com/ps/get-credential.html) cover you need.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can use that to "bundle up" some of the auth parameters, but I'd still need to say -credential $cred to every command in the pipeline ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing this cmdlets, or are you just using them in your scripts?
If you are writing these cmdlets in any OOP language, I think a way to do it is that you have a base cmdlet class, and every other cmdlets should extend that base cmdlet class. In this case, the base cmdlet class should initialize an object that stores your credential, and have a cmdlet to ask for credentials, which initialize the object. Every other cmdlets that extends the base class can therefore look for credential in this object.